# How to use "with" to improve scripts?

Tags: python, with-statement

I'm still fairly new to python, and I'm having a hard time understanding the "with" statement. I've read that it closes out files once it's finished, so it seems like it might be good for the script below.

As an example, I recently put together this script for renaming numbered files. At the end I haven't closed anything, although as far as I can tell the script works fine. So I guess my question is:

1. Do I need to close in this case?
2. If so, is a "with" statement appropriate?
3. If so, how would I use it?

```
import os
def main():

    src_dir = r"\\yolo-gisport01\D$\AssessorMaps\049"

    for filename in os.listdir(src_dir):

        if (len(filename) == 9):
            if filename[0] == "0":

                #create the full original file path as a variable to be used in the os.rename function
                src = src_dir + "\\" + filename

                #create the full new file path as a variable to be used in the os.rename function
                new_name = src_dir + "\\" + filename[-6:]

                # rename() function will take src (full file path) and rename new_name (full file path)
                os.rename(src, new_name)



# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Calling main() function
    main()
```

Comment: You never open anything, so there's no need to close.

Comment: See https://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Comment: @Barmar Oh really? I guess I assumed the os.rename function opened it but I guess it doensn't need to because I'm not actually writing to the file?

Comment: No, it doesn't. `os.listdir()` opens the directory, but it closes it when it's done.

Comment: And evevn if `os.rename()` opened the file, it would also close it. Unless the function returns a file object for you to call `close()` on, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Considering using `os.path.join(src_dir, filename)` instead of `src_dir + "\\" + filename`. You can then run the script on any OS without worrying about whether the separator should be `\ ` or `/`. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join

Comment: @GordonAitchJay I'll give that a try, thanks! That should work for new_name as well right? Like `new_name = os.path.join(src_dir, filename[-6:])`

Comment: Yes, that's right.